# Showing FlipviewController crash in XCode 4 debugger

Tags: xcode, ios4, debugging, ios-simulator

My app has 2 views that are shown as flipview when a button is pressed. They are working just fine on any testdevice.

But in XCode, one of them is causing a crash (bad_exec) to the return of the main method when he is displayed. The crash happens outside of any of my functions.

Ok, bad_exec means, I have anything that is trashing/deallocating or corrupting the memory.
But why does it just happen in the iPhone 4.2 simulator under xcode 4?
No Zombies do fire, nor do I overwrite/deallocate anything when he the view is displayed.

Any idea whats going on?
Added stack.
Full resolution here: http://www.codebaker.de/OddCrash.png

Changed to stack only
[image]

Comment: The stacktrace is empty?

Comment: Ok, now you got me. Where do I get the stack trace?

Comment: Can you post the stack only as a screenshot?

Comment: Ok, the app crashes when you run it just out of nothing, or when you flip the view? It looks like you are running an MPMoviePlayer instance?

Comment: Crash when flipping the view. Yes, there is a movie player. He isn't playing at that moment, but prepared. There is a second flip-view controller that have no issues and there is no crash on device, just in xcodes simulator.

Comment: Hmm this is hard to debug. Try to update to 4.3 and see if the crash still exists. This may ba a simulator bug.

Comment: Tried with deployment target to 4.3. Still crash. Tried with 4.3 simulator, no crash (4.2/4.3 deployment). Simulator bug?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it does look like it. Never ever trust the simulator! Always test on a device :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy Paste the stacktrace, look at the selection on the laft, it's a shortened stack trace, you can select and copy it:

[image]

You can find the stacktrace here, click on the field right to Thread 1 on the bar which divides the editor and the lower pane:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Well it is the return of the main that crashes. That function never returns on a iOS device and I am not returning in my app at that point. I dont get this.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me what with stack was meant! :) Is there a way to export the stack upon crash for posing without the need for screenshots?

Comment: Look again :) It should be there now.

Comment: Thanks. (trying)... hey thats cool. and a very obvious way to do it . blush.  :) tyvm

Comment: Oh actually I had to find out myself, else I would have told you in the first place. Anyway I still stick to XCode3 :)