# iOS app crashing - not sure what next place to look is

Tags: ios, ios5

I am working on a simple iOS app that I have taken over at work. I added a controller that has a UIWebView and is navigated to from a table view. I am able to do a pushViewController on it but when I navigate back, the app crashes at here:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    myWebView.delegate = nil;  // Thread 1 stopped at breakpoint 1
}
```

In the console, it says:

```
[Switching to process 621 thread 0x13b03]
[Switching to process 621 thread 0x18703]
[Switching to process 621 thread 0x11903]
```

Obviously, I've made some mistake but what would need the next place to look? I am using ARC.

thx

**edit 1**

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 974.
Pending breakpoint 1 - ""WebViewController.m":57" resolved
2012-03-19 08:11:05.888 SpotFinder[974:11903] Latitude = 37.785834
2012-03-19 08:11:05.889 SpotFinder[974:11903] Latitude = -122.406417
2012-03-19 08:11:06.030 SpotFinder[974:11903] here is a log of places 33
2012-03-19 08:11:11.030 SpotFinder[974:11903] You selected index_path: <NSIndexPath 0x705c0d0> 2 indexes [0, 2]
[Switching to process 974 thread 0x13a03]
[Switching to process 974 thread 0x15e03]
[Switching to process 974 thread 0x13a03]
[Switching to process 974 thread 0x11903]
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

**edit 2**
stacktrace:

[image]

Comment: Those console messages are irrelevant. What else does it say in the console?

Comment: @timpone [Stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5660248/296387)? [Zombies enabled](http://42games.net/quick-note-on-setting-nszombieenabled-environment-variable-in-xcode-4/)? [Breakpoint set for all exceptions set](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW38)?

Comment: Hmm... I get 'ARC forbids explicit message send of dealloc'

Comment: @sam Not when you're using ARC.

Comment: Adding Zombies enabled and breakpoint pieces now. Thx everbody for help. Just trying to get this to work.

Comment: @StephenDarlington You must've commented just before I removed my comment.  You are correct that in ARC it is actually a compiler error to call `[super dealloc]`.  We ran into problems awhile back where a random crash turned out to be from calling `[super dealloc]` and then releasing variables afterwords.  :: Bad juju!  But this was not in an ARC environment, so I always look for the `[super dealloc]` as the last line.

Comment: If you have the time, this new tutorial on RayWenderlich is exceptionally useful in familiarising oneself with debugging iOS apps: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever call dealloc directly whether it is in a non-ARC environment or with ARC enabled.

In non-ARC you call `release`, then the dealloc is called by the system on that particular object.

Dealloc with ARC enabled is called(again, by the system) when there is no reference any more on that object.

Comment: ugh - emberrassed to say this but when I started looking at line numbers, I realized that there was a second breakpoint and that the app actually wasn't crashing. Just frozen at a breakpoint. My mistake. Thx for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

When using ARC you can define a `dealloc` method to remove references and clean up resources, but you should not explicitly call `[super dealloc]`.

See [ARC Enforces New Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW14) which is part of [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

> You cannot explicitly invoke dealloc, or implement or invoke retain,
>   release, retainCount, or autorelease. The prohibition extends to using
>   @selector(retain), @selector(release), and so on.
>
> You may implement a dealloc method if you need to manage resources
>   other than releasing instance variables. You do not have to (indeed
>   you cannot) release instance variables, but you may need to invoke
>   [systemClassInstance setDelegate:nil] on system classes and other code
>   that isn’t compiled using ARC.
>
> **Custom dealloc methods in ARC do not require a call to [super dealloc]
>   (it actually results in a compiler error). The chaining to super is
>   automated and enforced by the compiler.**
>
> You can still use CFRetain, CFRelease, and other related functions
>   with Core Foundation-style objects (see “Managing Toll-Free
>   Bridging”).